# If I respec skills with a skill at level 4 ready to be morphed will I keep my progress?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

So I've got a few skills at level 4 unmorphed ready to be morphed, if I respecced would I still be ready to morph them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll keep all your experience/progress. If you don't learn it again it's still there. If you (re-)aquire that skill later (or respec again) the progress will still be there, even if you've leveled the other morph.